# C# Minimize to system tray on close

Tags: c#, system-tray

Hi In my c# application I am trying to minimize application to systems tray, when the form is closed. Here is the code I have tried.

```
   public void MinimizeToTray()
    {
        try
        {
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Sample text";
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Form is minimized";

            if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
            {
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);
                this.Hide();
            }
            else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
            {
                notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

and I am calling the method to form closing event. But the problem is its not minimizing to tray. Its just closing the form.

Comment: When the form is being closed or minimized?

Comment: Are you also cancelling/stopping the close event? This code wouldn't help much if the app gets closed anyway after this executes.

Comment: @HonzaBrestan trying to minimize it system tray when i click close button.

Comment: Possable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349709/c-sharp-close-to-tray-like-msn-messenger

Comment: Can you also provide the closing event code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Write a event in Form Closing event.

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
        e.Cancel = true;                         
        Hide();
 }
```

And write using Custom menu strip for notification icon for to show.

Comment: need to add the line in the constructor:
    this.FormClosing += this.Form1_FormClosing;

Answer (score 53):

`e.Cancel = true;` code will be always cancelling the event even if you shut the computer down, but here is a code that helps you:

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
     {
          myNotifyIcon.Visible = true;
          this.Hide();
          e.Cancel = true;
     }
 }
```

It will allow closing the form programmaticaly.

Comment: This solution is much better, because the solution of **arun kumar non ascii** is a never ending story :D

Comment: i experienced that if you don't set notifyIcon's icon image, then it is not shown in system tray in windows 8.1.

Comment: A great follow up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3233612/736893

Comment: good answer. Closing the form programmatically afterwards needs Application.Exit() and not this.Close().

Answer (score 4):

```
   namespace MinimizeTrayNotification
     {
      public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MinimzedTray()
    {
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application;

        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Minimized";
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Your Application is Running in BackGround";
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);

    }

    private void MaxmizedFromTray()
    {
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Maximized";
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Application is Running in Foreground";
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);


    }



    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(FormWindowState.Minimized==this.WindowState)
        {
        MinimzedTray();
        }
      else  if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
        {

            MaxmizedFromTray();
        }
        }

    private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.Show();
        MaxmizedFromTray();


    }

    private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.Hide();

        }


    }

    private void notifyIcon1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Normal";
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: I'm sure the code will work, but it will be even more helpful with a comment or two about what's going on!

Comment: for notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick, you should use `this.Show()` instead of making a new instance of a form. You'd probably want your forms controls to maintain their values.

Answer (score 2):

You should cancel the `FormClosing` event and then call your `MinimizeToTray()` function.

This is done through the `Cancel` property of the `FormClosingEventArgs`.

Also, consider using a `bool` somewhere to **allow** closing the `Form` in some conditions, such as if you're using a `File > Exit` menu or something:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(!allowClosing)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MinimizeToTray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the allowClosing, you can choose when to close with the FormClosingEventArgs:

    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }

Answer (score 1):

To minimize when closing set **WindowState** to **Minimized**

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = true;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the FormClosing-Event.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = true;
    MinimizeToTray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle `FormClosing` Event such as [micsoft Form Closing Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) as Following example of C#

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Determine if text has changed in the textbox by comparing to original text.
        if (textBox1.Text != strMyOriginalText)
        {
            // Display a MsgBox asking the user to save changes or abort.
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes to your text?", "My Application",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                // Cancel the Closing event from closing the form.
                e.Cancel = true;
                // Call method to save file...
            }
        }
}
```